# SwiftUI: Is there a way to assign a View to a variable for later use of the same instance?

Tags: ios, generics, swiftui, mvvm, protocol-oriented

I have a parent View:

```
struct ParentView<pViewModel> : View where pViewModel: ParentViewModel {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
             ChildView(viewModel: ViewModel(list:["a", "b", "c"]))
             ChildView(viewModel: ViewModel(list:["x", "y", "z"]))
        }
    }
}
```

In my child view, I have the following:

```
struct ChildView<cViewModel>: View where cViewModel: ChildViewModel {
    @ObservedObject var vm: cViewModel

    var body: some View {
         ...
    }
}
```

and this is the ViewModel of the child view:

```
protocol ChildViewModel: ObservableObject { ... }

class ChildViewModelImp: ChildViewModel {
     @Published var toggles: [String: Bool] = [:]
     var list: [String] = []

     init(list: [String]) {
        self.list = list

        for item in list {
            toggles[item] = false
        }
     }

     func toggleItem(item: String) {
          toggles[item].toggle()
     }
}
```

When an item in toggles gets toggled (via func toggleItem), both the parent view and the child view get re-rendered. The parent view creates a new instance of the child view so the viewModel init() is called again and I lose the data in the toggles property.

I tried saving the two child views into two properties in the parent View model, and call this in my Parent View like so:

```
struct ParentView<pViewModel> : View where pViewModel: ParentViewModel {

      @StateObject var vm: pViewModel

      var body: some View {
            vm.displayChildView(list: [...], isTop: true)
            vm.displayChildView(list: [...], isTop: false)
      }
}

protocol ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    associatedtype childVM: ChildViewModel
    func displayChildView(list: [String]) -> ChildView<childVM>
}

class ParentViewModelImp: ParentViewModel {
     private var childViewTop: ChildView<some ChildViewModel>?
     private var childViewBottom: ChildView<some ChildViewModel>?

     func displayChildView(list: [String], isTop: Bool) -> ChildView<some ChildViewModel> {
          if isTop {
             if childViewTop == nil {
                childViewTop = ChildView(viewModel: getChildViewModel(list: list))
             } else {
                return childViewTop
             }
          } else {
             if childViewBottom == nil {
                childViewBottom = ChildView(viewModel: getChildViewModel(list: list))
             } else {
                return childViewBottom
             }
         }
      }
      
      private func getChildViewModel(list: [String]) -> some ChildViewModel {
          var viewModel = ChildViewModelImp(list:list)
          ...
          return viewModel
      }
}
```

However it seems like the childViewTop and childViewBottom have different type from what getChildViewModel() returns.

Because of "some" keyword, it seems like my types do not match. How can I save the child views in variables so that I can reuse the same instance of the child views when it gets re-rendered and I don't lose my data in the child view model?

Comment: Maybe try rewriting this without ViewModels… it seems hugely complicated for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AshleyMills I need to have the ViewModels to make sure that I follow SOLID MVVM architecture.

Comment: In SwiftUI, you _could_ consider the View itself to be the view model. https://azamsharp.com/2022/07/17/2022-swiftui-and-mvvm.html. Whether or not you choose to have a view model, if you're having a problem try simplifying and building the views without them, fix the problem, then add them back.

Comment: If you are going to have a view model, then that needs to be bound to a *model* - the first *M* in *MVVM*. The view model should be an adapter on the model, so it doesn't matter if your view model gets recreated, as long as it gets recreated against the same model instance, it will have the data it needs. The view model should only store ephemeral data.  Also, using generics seems to be over complicating things. Are you really going to use the same view with a different view model?

Comment: @Paulw11 - sadly the generics is the result of having a protocol. I'm using protocol oriented programming in this project.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't mean that you should make *everything* a protocol.  When you find yourself saying "sadly" it may be an idea to question why you are using a protocol here.  Is the abstraction making your code simpler?  More maintainable? More flexible? Probably the answer to all of those is "no".  Regardless, the generics aren't the cause of your problem, the lack of a model is.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes! Thank you so much! When you mentioned "The view model should only store ephemeral data", I realized I needed to update my design a bit. :) It helped!

Comment: @Paulw11 Feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as such!